# String Format in Xcode

Tags: xcode, uitableview

The following will return data such as "14.00", "16.00". I would like to display it on the table cell as $14 $16

Thanks.

```
cell.lbl_Rental_Fee.text = [[self.responseData_In_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Rental_Fee_Hour"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want something like this assuming your value is a float

```
NSString *thing = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.0f", yourValue];
```

So in your example:

```
NSString *response = [[self.responseData_In_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Rental_Fee_Hour"];
float yourValue = [response floatValue];
cell.lbl_Rental_Fee.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.0f", yourValue];
```